# Creating a static page own theme

Tags: wordpress

I have used wordpress once for a single page website, but the client insists on using it again.

What I have done is created a my own theme with index.php file and placed there every info that needs to be displayed on the page. Then I activated this theme and it is working like I wanted it to work.

My problem is here - I want to add another Contact page and I want to hardcode the look and content of it, and probably the use of Contact Form 7.

And how am I supposed to do it? I can only choose one theme, but is it possible to choose a version of the theme so I can have 2 pages:

1. "Front page" with the front-page.php file from my theme
2. "Contact page" with the contact-page.php file from my theme

I will jump into wordpress after this project to know it a little bit better, but the client gave me 3 days to make this site so there is not much time for reading and understanding Wordpress now.

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to use same theme for contact page?